# `FieldValueQuery` is buggy

Tags: lucene

Or I misunderstand usage of this class. Check out the below code... (It is in Scala, but it should be easy to grasp the idea)

```scala
import org.apache.lucene.store._
import org.apache.lucene.document._
import org.apache.lucene.index._
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core._
import org.apache.lucene.search._

val directory = new RAMDirectory()
val config = new IndexWriterConfig(new WhitespaceAnalyzer())
val writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config)
writer.addDocument({
  val document = new Document()
  document.add(new StringField("foo", "bar", Field.Store.YES))
  document
})
writer.commit()

val searcher = new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(directory))

{
  val query = new ConstantScoreQuery(new FieldValueQuery("foo"))
  Console.println(searcher.search(query, 1).totalHits)
}

{
  val query = new TermQuery(new Term("foo", "bar"))
  Console.println(searcher.search(query, 1).totalHits)
}
```

the output is,

```
[info] 0
[info] 1
```

Is it a bug or I am missing anything ? (I am using Lucene 5.4.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FieldValueQuery` checks whether there is a `DocValue` for that field, not tranditional indexed/stored field content.  If you add a DocValuesField to the document, you should see it get a result for the query, such as:

```scala
val document = new Document()
document.add(new StringField("foo", "bar", Field.Store.YES))
document.add(new SortedDocValuesField("foo", new BytesRef("bar"))
document
```

Check out [the DocValues API](http://blog.trifork.com/2011/10/27/introducing-lucene-index-doc-values/), and [this blog post introducing them](http://blog.trifork.com/2011/10/27/introducing-lucene-index-doc-values/) for some information on what DocValues are all about.

Comment: Thank you! What if I just want to search for the documents that have a particular field? Before 5, I was using `FieldValueFilter`, and it worked like a charm. Now in 5 it is deprecated, I am wondering what should be used instead ?